# Virtual Smart Card PKCS#11 compliant

Tags: c, linux, smartcard, pkcs#11, opensc

I would like to run some tests on a virtual smart card. I would like to know if there exists a virtual smart card PKCS#11 compliant and supported by OpenSC. I'm running on Linux.

Thank you in advance for your valuable help. Best, BEE

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for a pure software implementation of PKCS#11 interface such as [SoftHSM](http://www.opendnssec.org/softhsm/) or [OpenCryptoki](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencryptoki/). You can also take a look at [Virtual Smart Card project](https://frankmorgner.github.io/vsmartcard/virtualsmartcard/README.html) but it will be slightly more complex to setup.

Comment: Do you have any guide to actually create a working smart card with Virtual Smart Card project, ie with a user certificate/private key?

Comment: @Evengard No I don't have any.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox includes the certificate storage accessible via PKCS#11 (note that their PKCS11 needs special form of initialization).